# Re-authenticate evernote app C#

Tags: c#, windows, api, evernote

The first time I authenticate the app with evernote I was greeted with the evernote sign in page, where I was able to auth my app. After revoking access, I was unable to access functions like uploading notes, or getting the list of notebooks. How can I force the reauth. process to occur again? I.E show the evernote login screen again at app launch. This is currently the code I have in my form.load():

```
// Be sure to put your own consumer key and consumer secret here.
ENSession.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey("your key", "your secret");

if (ENSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated == false)
{
    ENSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote();
}
```

I get no error when I run this, but when I try to upload a note I get this error:

```
Evernote.EDAM.Error.EDAMNotFoundException
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/blob/master/src/EvernoteSDK/ENSession.cs#L434), it looks like you may be able to set `ENSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated` to false and then call `ENSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote()`. Give that a shot and see if it works?

Comment: ENSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated is get only you can't set it. So I can't use this to fix the issue.

Comment: ah sorry, I don't speak C# :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but looks like you can call

```
ENSession.SharedSession.PerformPostAuthentication();
```

and then check

```
ENSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated.
```

If it evaluates to false, then loop back to call

```
ENSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote();
```

Comment: No this didnt work either. I'm still getting the same EDAM error as before. But thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I just stumbled across it as I was looking for something related.

It seems the Evernote SDK using ENSession or ENSession advanced does not provide a way to De-Authenticate.  However after de-compiling their dll I noticed that there is actually a Unauthenticate method that is private.  So in theory you could use reflection so call this method:

```
  var mi = typeof(ENSession).GetMethod("Unauthenticate", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);           
  mi.Invoke(ENSession.SharedSession, null);
```

I am sure that Evernote made this private for a reason so I would be careful calling it, but this should do the trick.  I tried this in one of my one Test Applications and after calling Unauthenticate I verified that ENSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated is false and calling ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote() does indeed launch a web browser asking you to log into Evernote.